# Evento de clique no Js, mudar a div

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tendo dificuldades em mudar as divs que possuo no HTML.

Minha ideia é que ao clicar uma vez, uma div seja exibida e a outra escondida. E caso o usuário clique de novo, essa div vai ficar escondida e a que estava escondida vai ficar visível. Não sei que lógica tenho que aplicar nisso. Pensei em evento de 2 cliques mas isso fica estranho pois tem que clicar duas vezes para exibir a outra. Seria se eu tô nessa, vou para a outra e vice versa.

O jeito que fiz com os 2 cliques:

```
var lista1 = document.getElementById('exercicio1e2');
var lista2 = document.getElementById('exercicio3e4')

function mudarExercicios(){
    lista1.style.display="flex";
    lista2.style.display="none";
}

function mudarExercicio2(){
    lista1.style.display="none";
    lista2.style.display="flex";
}
```

e no html meu botão:

```
    <button class="mudarExercicio" onclick="mudarExercicios()" ondblclick="mudarExercicio2()" >
        <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>
    </button>
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz de qual caminho devo seguir?

Comment: Cadê os elementos cujos os ids são `exercicio1e2` e `exercicio3e4`?

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma mais simples de fazer isso é criar um estilo que esconde a div, e usar o método `toggle` da lista de classes do elemento, ele adiciona uma classe se não existir, ou remove se já existir, daí basta por nessa classe o `display: none`.

Veja mais aqui: [https://developer.mozilla.org/toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

Um exemplo funcionando abaixo. Note que o `toggle` age sobre `classList`, que é a lista de classes que um elemento possui. Ambos elementos tem a classe "exercicio", e um deles vai ter também "esconder-exercicio", que vai alterar entre os dois:

```js
function mudarExercicios(){
   var lista1 = document.getElementById('exercicio1e2');
   var lista2 = document.getElementById('exercicio3e4')
   
   lista1.classList.toggle("esconder-exercicio");
   lista2.classList.toggle("esconder-exercicio");
}
```

```css
.exercicio {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #000
}

.esconder-exercicio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="exercicio1e2" class="exercicio">Olá, sou o elemento exercicio1e2</div>
<div id="exercicio3e4" class="exercicio esconder-exercicio">Olá, sou o elemento exercicio3e4, tudo bem?</div>

<button class="mudarExercicio" onclick="mudarExercicios()">
   <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>Mudar Exercicio
</button>
```