# Mostrar/Ocultar Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com dificuldade em ocutar mais de uma div usando o Javascript eu gostaria de saber se ah uma maneira de ocultar varias div's sem ter que copiar o mesmo codigo do JS.

Eu fiz isso HTML:

```
  <button id="modelos">Modelo 1</button>
  <div class="categoria">
    <li data-id="1">
      <span>Categoria 1</span>
    </li>
  </div>

  <button id="modelos2">modelo 2</button>
  <div class="categoria categoria2">
    <li data-id="2">
      <span>categoria 2</span>
    </li>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.categoria,
.categoria2 {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#modelos');

var categoria = document.querySelector('.categoria');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
if(categoria.style.display === 'block'){
    categoria.style.display = 'none';
} else{
    categoria.style.display = 'block';
}
});
```

ai no caso para eu ocultar e mostrar a outra div eu tinha que copiar o JS e colar novamente com um nome diferente, gostaria de saber se tem um jeito mais simplis. tem como?

Comment: não precisa mudar usando `style.display`, já tem uma classe com `display: none`, basta adicionar/remover essa classe para alterar vários elementos, veja essa resposta com um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/507244/evento-de-clique-no-js-mudar-a-div

Comment: Tem como sim usando forEach()

Comment: **ANTES DE RESPONDER A PERGUNTA** Veja esse exemplo https://codepen.io/AugustoVasques/pen/mdWJxxZ , não está como resposta porque não usa javascript, mas note que o usuário quer um botão para cada div e não um botão para todas as divs.

Answer (score -3):

Em javascript puro, você pode criar uma função para facilitar e economizar códigos.

**Exemplo:**

```
function exibir(IDOBJETO,CLASSECSS){
var btn = document.querySelector(IDOBJETO);
var categoria = document.querySelector(CLASSECSS);
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(categoria.style.display === 'block'){
        categoria.style.display = 'none';
    } else{
        categoria.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

}

para chamar a função:

```
exibir('#modelos','.categoria')
```

Para carregar a função automaticamente com o load da página pode fazer pela tag Body por exemplo

```
<body onload="exibir('#modelos','.categoria')">
```

Comment: O usuário quer um botão para cada div. E não um botão para todas as divs.